# Transfer photos from iPhone 5 to Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: osx-lion, itunes, iphone

I am trying to transfer a few pics from my Macbook to my iPhone. I read your previous answer. Due to my tech lack of know-how, I am unable to even get started.

I can not find any photo tab in iTunes. Where should I look. I just want to use the usb port and connect it to my phone and transfer some pics. Help. I am sure this is something simple I am not doing I have the latest iTunes on my computer.

Comment: which previous answer are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need a folder where you can put all the pictures you want to sync. So, create one, e.g. in `Documents` and then copy your photos there.

[image]

Now connect your iPhone. iTunes will open. Click *iPhone* – or click the name of your iPhone in the sidebar in case you use the old iTunes, but I would suggest you install the new iTunes version through the Mac App Store. It's much faster than iTunes 10.

[image]

Here, you can click the *Photos* tab. Add the folder you just created in your Documents. To do this, click the dropdown menu next to *Sync Photos from*, click *Choose folder…* and select your folder.

[image]

In the bottom right, click *Apply*, and then *Sync*. Your photos will be transferred to your iPhone, into their own "gallery" named after the folder you created before.